# Finding NSManagedObject inside of NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I thought that `[moc existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&error]` was the right way to find an existing object inside of a thread, given its `objectID`, but I can't get it to work, why?

### Background / Code

I've got an `NSManagedObject` which is already saved. I can see all its properties on the main thread. I'm passing the object to my `NSOperation` in a custom `init` method and in that method, I'm saving its `objectID`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithEntity:(NSManagedObject *)object
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.objectID = object.objectID;
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in the `main` function of my operation I'm looking up my object so that I can use it.

```
- (void)main
{
    if (self.isCancelled) { return; }

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.object = [moc existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&error];

    if (error) {
        DDLogError(@"error finding object: %@", error);
    }

    ...
}
```

`MR_context` is a MagicalRecord method which simply sets up a new context with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` with its parent set to the root saving context. All of that looks correct to me.

### Errors

When no debugger is set, I simply get a `fault` for the object. If I try to look up any property on it, I get `nil`.

With the debugger turned on and `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` set I get some errors:

In the simulator I get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on the `[moc existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&error]` line.

On the device, I get the following on that same line:

```
CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:
->  0x185946614 <+0>: brk    #0x1
```

So obviously something is wrong, but the `objectID` isn't temporary, it is the same `objectID` I see when inspecting the real object on the main thread. So I'm not sure why it isn't working.

I've also tried:

```
self.object = [moc objectWithID:self.objectID];
```

But that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

### Updates

2015-07-10 - Ok, if I use a block with the `moc` then I can properly access the object from within that block.

```
[moc performBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *o = [moc existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&error];
}];
```

How do I properly extract that object so I can have access to it in the thread that the operation is running? Doing a `__block` property and then setting it in the block and using it out of the block failed.

Is this an issue with the way the [context](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Threads.md#creating-custom-contexts) is setup?

Comment: You mentioned it's not a temporary id - just checking did you test that by calling `isTemporaryID` the on the objectID?

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry, I should have come back to answer this. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MagicalRecord's context sets up its own queue to perform operations on it. Therefore, if you want to use it to look something up, you have to do it in a block (`[context performBlock:]` or `[context performBlockAndWait:]`) so that it can perform it on its own queue and then return back to the `NSOperation`.

What I ended up doing was creating a couple `__block` properties and then pulling the needed contents from the object outside of the block.